# Condition with JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, mapbox, mapbox-android

I was wondering if it was possible to use conditions with JSON.
Let me explain, I would like to check a condition when the route indicates to turn left or right. I use mapbox as a navigation SDK.

In their technical documentation, he tells us that we can use `StepManeuver` object:

### Example:

```
{
  "bearing_before": 299,
  "bearing_after": 202,
  "type": "turn",
  "modifier": "left",
  "location": [
    13.424671,
    52.508812
  ],
  "instruction": "Turn left onto Adalbertstraße"
}
```

What interests me is the value `modifier` which can be associated with "left" or "right".

So I would like to create a condition "if turn left then [...]" and "if turn right then [...]". But I do not know if this is possible and I do not know how to do it, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with just reading the value from that json string and then performing some conditional check?

Comment: As @ZUNJAE said, the simplest thing to do is to get the `modifier` attribute value and check it.

Comment: Thank you but how do you first get "modifier"?

Answer (score -1):

If i got your question.then simply.

```
if(modifier.equalas("left")
     // do left oper..
else if(modifier.equalas("right")
     // do right oper..
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it must be that surely but in android studio it does not detect "modifier" yet I import the service "stepmaneuver" of mapbox.

Comment: @Atomike-Toxic `modifier` is just a String variable you will get from JSONObject.. eg:- `String modifier = yourJsonObj.getString("modifier");`